# Why is Windows 10 \bin directory special

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions

*There is no understanding or explanation yet.*

I have two directories, `C:\bin` and `C:\Intel\bin`.

My path is `...;C:\bin;...;C:\Intel\bin;...`

I have `sed.exe` which is a GNU build for Windows XP.

I copy this to `C:\bin` (using cmd.exe copy as user) and the system asks to run it as administrator, but from `C:\Intel\bin` it is OK.

The permissions etc on all the directories \bin, \intel, \intel\bin are the same:

```
SYSTEM, 
Administrators (PC\Administrators), 
User (PC\User)
```

All permissions ticked: Full Control, Modify, Read and execute, List folder contents, Read, Write

All directories have inheritance disabled.
All directories are owned by SYSTEM

Nothing has special permissions ticked.

What is special about `\bin`?

[Properties of all directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K05kX.png)

Both sed.exe are owned by User (PC\User)
Both sed.exe have the same permissions.

[Properties of both executables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKc11.png)

**LATEST**

I have now proved that the critical factor in this is what the directory is called. If the directory is called \bin then programs compiled on the PC can run from it but programs downloaded from the internet will not but if the directory is renamed to \newbin then all programs will run from that directory.

The security properties of \bin and \newbin are identical.

[Properties of \bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KflHF.png)

[Properties of \newbin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Eru.png)

[Renaming bin to newbin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjzRr.png)

Comment: This folder is not part of Windows 10 even on a completely Intel machine (graphics, CPU, and Network cards).

Comment: I've spotted a difference in permissions, so I've updated my answer. Next time, don't post an answer if you really should be editing your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

C:\bin is not a folder used by windows. There is nothing special about this folder normally.

There must be a permission issue about c:\bin that causes your user to not be allowed to write to it, and thus asking for administrative privileges. So even though the rights may be the same, something must be different that makes this behave differently.

One thing that I can think of, is ownership of the folder. Even if you do not have any rights of the folder, if you have ownership of the folder, you still am allowed to do stuff. You can see who's owner by going to the permission folder, advanced settings, owner  is at the top.

Its very likely that TrustedInstaller is owner of c:\bin, whereas your own user is owner in c:\intel\bin. This is often if Windows Updates created the c:\bin folder by installing an update for a driver, wheras you created c:\intel\bin by installing a driver yourself.

EDIT: based on the screenshots in the now deleted answer (because really, that is not an answer, it should have been an edit to your question)

The difference is indeed a rights issue. The C:\Bin folder has permissions set for the GROUP users, where as c:\intel\bin has permission set for the USER user. If the USER user is not in the GROUP users, its not gonna work. Assign the USER user the full control rights, I'm positive it will work then.

Comment: I think that I can provide evidence here that there must be something else going on :

![link](http://example.com)

Comment: Hello Journeyman Geek,

What is the reason for deleting my post?

Comment: @Questaware your post is actually an answer, but you did not answer your question. You should edit your question instead to provide additional information. Moderators actively check for this in order to make sure new users to SuperUser make the mistake only once, learn from it and edit their own posts the next time. :)

Comment: I have edited the question as there is no explanation yet.

Comment: See my Edit. the difference is USER user vs GROUP users.

Comment: The permissions on everything are now the same but the difference remains. I also copied sed.exe to \newbin and it runs there.